# Why does UITabBarController deliver wrong size to hidden views in viewWillTransitionToSize?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

In iOS 8, I'm moving my code to rely on `viewWillTransitionToSize` to adjust my viewControllers that are under a UITabBarController. However, when a view is not currently being displayed, the sizes being delivered to it are incorrect.

I wrote a tiny program to isolate the problem. It simply creates two VCs, labels them, puts them in a TabBarController, and then reports the size delivered to viewWillTransitionToSize. If you want to recreate this, you can replace a dummy projects AppDelegate.m with the following code.

The output is below the program. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround to get the right upcoming size?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * detailItem;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSLog(@"%@ will transition from %@ to %@",self.detailItem, NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size), NSStringFromCGSize(size));
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    MyViewController * firstVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    firstVC.detailItem = @"Bookmark controller";
    firstVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:0];

    MyViewController *secondVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    secondVC.detailItem = @"History controller";
    secondVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItemHistory tag:1];

    UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers: @[firstVC, secondVC]];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController =  tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


@end
```

The output is as follows:

```
<<starting in Bookmark VC in Portrait; transition to Landscape>>
Bookmark controller will transition from {375, 667} to {667, 375}  <<Correct>>
History controller  will transition from {375, 667} to {0, 0}      <<Very wrong>>

<<transition back to Portrait>>
Bookmark controller will transition from {667, 375} to {375, 667}  <<Correct>>
History controller  will transition from {375, 667} to {667, 375}  <<Wrong>>

<<switch to History tab; transition to Landscape>>
Bookmark controller will transition from {375, 667} to {375, 667}  <<Wrong>>
History controller  will transition from {375, 667} to {667, 375}  <<Correct; note prev wrong size is now correct without notification>>

<<transition back to Portrait>>
Bookmark controller will transition from {375, 667} to {375, 667}  <<Correct but still wrong current size>>
History controller will transition from {667, 375} to {375, 667}   <<Correct>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to fix this issue using the code below. I am not sure if this is 100% right so if anybody has a good solution then please let us know.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    for viewController in viewControllers! {
        viewController.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to call the viewWillTransitionToSize to the presentedViewController if there is one. if ([self presentedViewController])
    {
        [[self presentedViewController] viewWillTransitionToSize:size
                                       withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

Answer (score 0):

No; frankly, I cheated, and used the following version of `viewWillTransitionToSize` (in the real program, this is in a subclass of Apple's AAPLTraitOverrideViewController to let me do the dual pane on iPhone 6).

It relies on the fact that the VC in the currently selected tab has got the correct, old frame size, so when `viewWillTransitionToSize` is called for an non-selected tab, it looks to its sibling to give it the real size. Then it applies the current transform and takes absolute values to avoid negative numbers. Note this will only work if the VCs are immediate children of the tab controller.

If you (or anyone) come up with a better approach, let me know!

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSLog(@"%@ will transition from %@ to %@",self.detailItem, NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size), NSStringFromCGSize(size));
    CGSize realSize = size;
    if (self.tabBarController) {
        //workaround for inaccurate sizes being delivered to non-selected tabs
        NSArray * viewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
        NSUInteger myIndex = [viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
        NSUInteger selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex != myIndex && myIndex != NSNotFound && selectedIndex != NSNotFound) {
            //not on screen, so use size from selected tab, transformed as indicated by coordinator
            UIViewController * selectedVC = viewControllers[selectedIndex];
            CGSize newSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(selectedVC.view.frame.size, [coordinator targetTransform]);
            realSize = CGSizeMake(fabsf(newSize.width), fabsf(newSize.height));
            NSLog(@"  Instead of: %@, rotating to correct size: %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(size),NSStringFromCGSize(realSize));
        }
    }
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:realSize withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mackworth. I tried with subclass UITabBarController and there I call viewWillTransitionToSize and in this method I go throught all view controllers in the tab bar and call directly viewWillTransitionToSize passing the correct size.

Comment: So, still cheating, but now at a higher level!  Can you post your code for that?  You don't find any side effects of not letting uitabVC handle that viewWillTransitionToSize call? (And why the heck is UITabVC not handling such an obvious case?)

Comment: Look at the answer I posted. I didn't find yet any side effects but you should test it in your project.